# How to get number of elements in array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have an array of `sruct sockaddr_in`:

```
struct sockaddr_in saddrlist[MAX] = {0};
```

the array is also being updated from external sources with memcpy, so thats the point where i dont know anymore about the count. and currNumOfelements.

Now at some point, i want to check how many elements are in the array.
What I tried:

```
printf("before: %d",getsize(saddrlist));
memcpy(&myotherlist, saddrlist, sizeof(saddrlist) * MAX);
printf("after: %d",getsize(saddrlist));
```

Which results in:

```
before: 52448
after:  52448
```

```
int getsize(struct sockaddr_in saddrlist[10])
{
    uint8_t numOfElements = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        if (saddrlist[i] != 0)
            numOfElements++;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because `if (saddrlist[i] != 0)` is an invalid comparison.. but how do i do it then? I get so confused using `c`..

Comment: What's the purpose of variable `currNumOfElements` then?

Comment: If your array is updated from an external source, then you must ensure that this external source updates `currNumOfElements` too, or that it provides some other mechanism to determine whether it changed the number of valid elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your variable `currNumOfElements` to determine how many elements are in the array. Because it's a static array, `saddrlist` will always have `MAX` elements in it. You get to decide what's a 'valid' configuration for your struct, and what's 'invalid'.

Comment: check the edit, my bad

Comment: I checked your edit, and my answer should still suffice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `memcmp` the addresses to a zero initialized one:

```
int getsize(struct sockaddr_in *saddrlist)
{
    int numOfElements = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in zero = { 0 };  // declare a local "null" sockaddr_in
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (memcmp(saddrlist + i, &zero, sizeof(zero)) != 0)
            numOfElements++;
        else break;                   // stop at first "null" address
    }
    return numOfElements;
}
```